# How to change custom blade directive value dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-cache

I'm trying to make a blade directive for [`Stichoza /google-translate-php`](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php) package. But when I change the language from menu it change once. When I try to change it again it will not change. It will only work when I run `php artisan view:clear` command.

Here is my directive in `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('translate',function ($text){
        $lang =app()->getLocale();
        $changedText = GoogleTranslate::trans($text, $lang, 'en');

        return "<?php echo $changedText; ?>";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a static string since once the blade view is compiled to PHP and cached the PHP in that file isn't going to change which is just you echoing a string (that will not change since it is a static string).

You would want the returned PHP from the directive to be getting the locale and calling `GoogleTranslate::trans` if you want this to actually be dynamic as the PHP in the compiled version of the blade view is what is ran every time the view is rendered, not the blade directive (there is no Blade at this point).